# Python write to list to CSV

Tags: python, list, csv

My write to CSV statement isn't working properly;

I have a list with strings in each that each need to be written to their own line in  csv;

```
mylist = ['this is the first line','this is the second line'........]
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(mylist)
```

The problem is, my output gets  messed up somewhere and looks like this;

```
't,h,i,s, i,s, t,h,e, f,i,r,s,t, l,i,n,e,'.... etc.
```

I need to be;

```
'this is the first line'
'this is the second line'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`csvwriter.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) should be used with sequence (or iterable) of sequences. (The `mylist` is also a sequence of sequences because string can be seen as a sequence of single-character-strings)

Use [`csvwriter.writerow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) for every `mylist` items instead:

```
mylist = ['this is the first line','this is the second line'........]
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in mylist:
        writer.writerow([row])
```

To use `writerows`, convert the list to sequence of sequences:

```
mylist = ['this is the first line','this is the second line'........]
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    rows = [[row] for row in mylist]
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to iterate the list items like

```
  mylist = ['this is the first line','this is the second line']
  with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f)
      for item in mylist:
          writer.writerow([item])
```